# Run method is not getting executed for class Task which is of Type Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading, in the below given I am trying to sum the value of a and b from all the task and save it in *finalAnswer* variable. But somehow my run method is not getting triggered. Please, let me know what is missing. There may be a lot of silly mistakes apologies for the same.

```
package MultiThreading;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Executor {

static List<Task> list = new LinkedList<Task>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task t1 = new Task(1, 2, "u1");
    Task t2 = new Task(3, 4, "u2");
    Task t3 = new Task(5, 6, "u3");
    Task t4 = new Task(7, 8, "u1");
    Task t5 = new Task(9, 10, "u2");
    Task t6 = new Task(11, 12, "u3");
    Task t7 = new Task(13, 14, "u1");
    Task t8 = new Task(15, 16, "u2");
    Task t9 = new Task(17, 18, "u3");

    list.add(t1);
    list.add(t2);
    list.add(t3);
    list.add(t4);
    list.add(t5);
    list.add(t6);
    list.add(t7);
    list.add(t8);
    list.add(t8);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    list.stream().forEach(x -> executor.submit(() -> new Task(x.a, x.b, x.userName)));

    System.out.println(" finalAnswer " + Task.finalAnswer);

}

static class Task implements Runnable {

    int a;
    int b;
    String userName;

    public Task(int a, int b, String userName) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.userName = userName;
        System.out.println(" a " + a + " b " + b + " userName " + userName);
    }

    static Integer finalAnswer = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finalAnswer += (a + b);
        System.out.println(" Thread info " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

}

Please, suggest.

Comment: Why do you create `new Task(...)` from an existing `Task` inside the `forEach`? Why not just `.forEach(executor::submit)`?

Comment: "But somehow my run method is not getting triggered" it looks like you're not waiting for them to be triggered before printing `finalAnswer`.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
list.stream().forEach(x -> executor.submit(() -> new Task(x.a, x.b, x.userName)));
```

doesn't do what I think you think it does.

This is submitting a runnable which simply creates a new task. Effectively:

```
list.stream().forEach(x -> executor.submit(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    new Task(x.a, x.b, x.userName);
  }
});
```

which doesn't actually run the `Task.run()` method.

So, you could:

- Invoke `run()` directly: `() -> new Task(x.a, x.b, x.userName).run()`
- Submit the `new Task`: `executor.submit(new Task(x.a, x.b, x.userName))`
- But why create new `Task`s anyway, when `Task` implement `Runnable`: `executor.submit(x)` (or go even simpler, with `list.forEach(executor::submit)`).

But then you have problems with the atomicity and visibility of the updates to the `finalAnswer` variable.

- `finalAnswer += (a + b);` isn't atomic: it is `finalAnswer = finalAnswer + (a + b)`. Nothing prevents another thread from writing to `finalAnswer` in between the read and the write.
- `System.out.println(" finalAnswer " + Task.finalAnswer);` doesn't guarantee to see the updated value of `finalAnswer`.

The simplest solution to this is to mutually synchronize access to the `finalAnswer` variable:

```
synchronized (Task.class) {
  System.out.println(" finalAnswer " + Task.finalAnswer);
}

//

synchronized (Task.class) {
  finalAnswer += (a * b);
}
```

Other solutions such as using `AtomicInteger` also exist.

But in general, this is a very poor use of the executor framework: it would be better to submit `Callable<Integer>` to the executor, and add up all of the results in the main thread instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy - I have updated the modified solution. Could you please let me know how can I use the callable here to make it better?

Comment: don't do that otherwise question/answer gets out of sync

Answer (score 0):

You can use `executor.submit(task)` in the for loop, which triggers the tasks to run in different threads. And to see that its running you need to wait on main thread before you print finalAnswer using `Thread.currentThread().join` or kind of sleep(someLongPeriod)

So that individual tasks are run in worker threads while main thread is waiting. Once execution over you can print finalAnswer

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {
    static AtomicInteger finalAnswer = new AtomicInteger(0) ;
    static List<Task> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        list.add(new Task(1, 2, "u1"));
        list.add(new Task(3, 4, "u2"));
        list.add(new Task(5, 6, "u3"));
        list.add(new Task(7, 8, "u1"));
        list.add(new Task(9, 10, "u2"));
        list.add(new Task(11, 12, "u3"));
        list.add(new Task(13, 14, "u1"));
        list.add(new Task(15, 16, "u2"));
        list.add(new Task(17, 18, "u3"));

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        list.forEach(executor::submit);
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
        System.out.println(" finalAnswer " + Main.finalAnswer);

    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    int a;
    int b;
    String userName;

    Task(int a, int b, String userName) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.userName = userName;
        System.out.println(" a " + a + " b " + b + " userName " + userName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Main.finalAnswer.getAndAdd(a + b);
        System.out.println(" Thread info " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have got to evoke method run() to start your thread. But if you wanted to calculate your finalAnsert of all threads you should create the variable finalAnswer out of calss Task. And one very important thing in the string with while (!executor.isTerminated()) {} this sting allow print finalAnswer when all threads finished its work

Comment: Thanks, @Marat - Currently as all threads are executing tasks parallelly. 
But how can I ensure that tasks for the same user should run sequentially and for two different user paralelly?

Comment: Also, you need to be sure that threads would not modify the variable simultaneously. For achieving this purpose you can use Atomic variables.

Comment: For achieving this purpose you need to change a lot off in your cod. Yout can read about it here    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945308/processing-tasks-in-parallel-and-sequentially-java